# Plotting species distribution on map in R

Tags: r

I'd like to plot the distribution of a species on a map of Switzerland, following [this tutorial](http://www.molecularecologist.com/2012/09/making-maps-with-r/).

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

map('worldHires', 'Switzerland', xlim=c(5, 12), ylim=c(45,48))
```

From [this website](http://www.euforgen.org/distribution-maps/) I download the shapefile for e.g. *Pinus sylvestris*

```
psylvestris <- readShapePoly("Pinus sylvestris.shp")
```

I want to add the range to the map:

```
plot(psylvestris, add=TRUE, xlim=c(5, 12), ylim=c(45,48))
```

But I do not see anything (other than the map).. It appears to me the coordinates might be given in a different system (?)

```
> psylvestris
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 52 
extent      : -1202142, 4710481, -925131.2, 6334053  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 1
names       : Id 
min values  :  0 
max values  :  0
```

Unfortunately I do not know anything about spatial analysis and thus I have no idea how to fix this. Can you help me please?

Comment: I would like to transform separate coordinate expressed in the Swiss reference system LV95 into LatLong/WGS84. Do you think it would be possible to do this in R using using a similar way as in this example?

Comment: this is another question, please create a new question

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to re-project the shapefile to  LatLong/WGS84 (`spTransform()`) :

```
library("maps")
library("mapdata")
library("rgdal")

psylvestris <- readOGR("Pinus Sylvestris.shp", "Pinus Sylvestris")
proj4string(psylvestris)
# [1] "+proj=laea +lat_0=48 +lon_0=9 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378388 +b=6378388 +units=m +no_defs"

psylvestris <- spTransform(psylvestris, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
proj4string(psylvestris) 
# [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

plot(psylvestris, xlim=c(5, 12), ylim=c(45,48), axes=TRUE)
map("worldHires", "Switzerland", add=TRUE, col="red", lwd=3)
```

[image: map]