# Transforming coordinate in Swiss reference system LV95 into LatLong/WGS84?

Tags: r, coordinate-system

I would like to transform coordinates expressed in the Swiss reference system [LV95](http://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/internet/swisstopo/en/home/topics/survey/sys/refsys/switzerland.html) into LatLong/WGS84. On the website of the Swiss  topography centre, there is an [application](http://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/internet/swisstopo/en/home/apps/calc/reframe.html) to do so, however altitude data are required and I don't have them.

In [Plotting species distribution on map in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112249), the user also wants to convert from Lv95 into LatLong. I was wondering if the solution he gets (reprojecting his shapefile into lat/long) could also work for me, as I don't have a shapefile but just separate coordinates.

Comment: The application you link to does not appear to *require* altitude data, unless you check that box for step 3. Per the instructions "if needed". As for the other solution, you'd likely have to first create points out of your coordinates, and then reproject it.

Comment: I thought that the application did not require altitude data at first too, but when I tried it, I got a box message saying that altitude data were necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This it's very easy using r package `sp`.

But you should give an example of your data. I'm going to suppose that you have a table with the points coordinates. And you can save this table on CSV format.

```
library(sp)

test <- read.csv("test.points.csv")

# We create a Spatial points data frame for our data, where X and Y are the fields with coordinates
coordinates(test) <- ~ X + Y

# We tell R our data it's on LV95, EPSG=2056
test@proj4string <- CRS("+init=epsg:2056")

# We can check the original coords
test@coords

# We can plot the data to check
plot(test)

# Then we transform the data to WGS84
test2 <- spTransform(test, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

# We can see the transformed coords
test2@coords
```